# How to embed a sip softphone in a webpage?

Tags: http, sip

I wish to embed a sip phone into a web page. How can i achieve this. Is there any available open source solution or I will have to develop it myself? I will be using this sip phone with asterisk.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at sipML5. It is one of the first open source SIP clients using HTML5. It is written in JavaScript, uses Web Real Time Communication (WebRTC), and supports voice and video calling as well as text messages. The client should work on any web browser supporting WebRTC without the need for any plugins and is therefore suitable for embedding web sites. However, only the latest browsers like Chrome Canary support WebRTC.

Multi-party video conferencing etc. is not implemented yet.

http://www.sipml5.org/

Comment: Be advised : You will have problems supporting IE with this option as IR doe not fully support webRTC.

Answer (score 3):

Following permutations and combinations i tried , if that helps :

1. JS SIP + OVER SIP using WebRTC
2. HttpRA + netty library + Rhino Telecom Application Server
3. SIP JS + Office SIP + Flash plugin + sip over UDP
   -> big success
4. Mobicent + Office SIP + Flash plugin + sip over UDP
   -> success
5. Websocket Client-server + Rhino
   -> Failed ,  Http handshake over WS with subprotocol SIP using websockets client and server is not feasible for large transactions , results in port blocking
6. Asterix :
   : Under Process  , Phones can successfully send sip signals but no communication due to codec incompatibility
7. SIPML5+ Office SIP + WebRTC + sip over WS + DNS Server/ port forwarding
   : system crashed due to heavy messing with ports !!!

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is Java applets (which are old, but are capable of doing such things).

I suggest you look for ready-made solutions implemented by java applets, or if you can't find any, try using any of the open-source sip-phones implemented in java (like [MJSIP](http://www.mjsip.org/)), and create an applet for it.